# Android emulator - Cannot take screenshot - Unsupported protocol: 2

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.uitest

I'm using Xamarin.UITest to run tests on android emulator. Tests run successfully, but screenshot file is absent at desired folder.
There is an error message in log file:

```
12:12:03 E/Screenshot: Unsupported protocol: 2
Could not take screenshot
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.saveImage(Unknown Source)
    at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source)
    at sh.calaba.screenshot.ScreenshotTaker.main(Unknown Source)

04-07-2018 12:12:03.738 +03:00 - 9038 - Took screenshot. { Path: "C:\Source\Repos\MyApp\MyApp.UITests\bin\Release\screenshot-1.png", Title: "Welcome screen." }
```

initialization:

```
return ConfigureApp
    .Android
    .EnableLocalScreenshots()
    .ApkFile("../../../MyApp.Android/bin/Release/com.myapp.MyApp-Signed.apk")
    .StartApp();
```

test:

```
AppResult[] results = app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("mainPage"));
app.Screenshot("Welcome screen.");
Assert.IsTrue(results.Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has fixed with latest Calabash for Android 8.1

Ref: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/pull/866

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem on my real device, but now I have resolved my problem.
When I was facing this problem, at that time I was using Android SDK Tools with version 25.0.0 and SDK platform with version Android 10.0(Q).
So I have updated my SDK Tools version to 26.1.1 and also I got switched to SDK Platform Android 8.1(Oreo). These steps solved my problem now I am able to take screenshot on uiautomatorviewer.
I have updated SDK Tools and SDK platform using Android studio.
Please check if these steps can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

update version of ddmlib.jar to 26.0.0-dev would solve this.